# Expanding <TD> causes content to wrap to next line

Tags: html, css

My problem is that content inside a `TD` will wrap to next line instead of expanding the parent table. I can't understand what would be the limit at which the `table` stops expanding.

What I want is to prevent content to jump onto next row.
The problem is described here https://jsfiddle.net/9o1cvbwk/3/:

- Press 'Add' several times.
- the table keeps expanding up the point it reaches the width of the screen (OK)
- Pressing 'Add' again will cause the 'V' link to jump to next row, right under the input button ( NOK )
- Pressing 'Add' again will cause the `table` to expand beyond the limit of the screen ( NOK - correct to expand but without the 'v' link sliding to the next row )

Really looking forward to opinions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent "V" link to jump to next row, simply add `white-space: nowrap` to `td`.

`white-space` defines what to do, when browser meets some whitespace (space, tab, etc). If we set it to `nowrap`, browser will not wrap our content if there will be not enought space.

When the table expand beyond boundaries, the "V" is collapsing to next row, because of no space.

in your css add:

```
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/66c93hgv/

Comment: Explain in your answer why this works and for what this property stands for.

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code and explanation in your answer (and not just provide a link to jsfiddle), this is to prevent link rot. Please [edit] your  answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks for advices for newbee :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: white-space: nowrap - right, what was i thinking :)